# How to check if all needed subscribers finished their work?

Tags: java, spring, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have the following scheme when using rx entities:

```
    Observerable1
        |
------------------
|       |         |   
S1(*)  S2(*)     S3 (onCompleted() starts another observable)
                  |
              Observable2
                  |
                 S4(*)
```

I need to know when all of subscribers with `*` finish their work (`S1,S2,S4`). As they can execute in different threads I need some sync mechanism or there is some out of the box solution from `rx-java` ?

Some sample code to illustrate current design:

```
@Component
public class BatchReader {
    @Autowired List<Subscriber<List<Integer>>> subscribers;

    public void start() {
        ConnectableObservable<List<Integer>> observable1 = createObservable();
        subscribers.forEach(observable1::subscribe);
        observable1.connect();
    }

    private ConnectableObservable<List<Integer>> createObservable() {
        return Observable.create((Subscriber<? super List<Integer>> subscriber) -> {
            try {    
                subscriber.onStart();

                while (someCondition) {
                    List<Integer> numbers = ...;
                    subscriber.onNext(numbers);
                }

                subscriber.onCompleted();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                subscriber.onError(ex);
            }
        }).observeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).publish();
    }
}
```

In S3 I have following logic:

```
@Component
public class S3 extends Subscriber<List<Integer>> {
    @Autowired AnotherBatchReader anotherBatchReader;
    ....
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        anotherBatchReader.start();
    }
    ...
}
```

And S4 subscribes in AnotherBatchReader:

```
@Component
public class AnotherBatchReader {
    @Autowired S4<List<Foo>> subscriber4;

    public void start() {
        Observable<List<Foo>> observable2 = createObservable();
        observable2.subscribe(subscriber4);
    }

    private Observable<List<Foo>> createObservable() {
        return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
            try {
                    subscriber.onStart();
                    while (someConditionBar) {
                        List<Foo> foo = ...;
                        subscriber.onNext(foo);
                    }
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                subscriber.onError(ex);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So is there a way to be properly notified when all subscribers I'm interested in done their work ? Is rx supports it out the box ? Or maybe there is a better design that will support it ?

**EDIT:**
I have separate subscribers, because each one have different behaviour. At the end subscribers with `*` (S1,S2,S3) will write their data to xml files. But

- S1 receives data in `onNext()`, doing some work, and writes results directly to files
- S2 receives data in `onNext()`, doing some work, accumulates results in field and then writes it with `onCompleted`
- S3 receives data in `onNext`, doing some work, writes results to DB and after `onCompleted` is called starts another observable which begin to get data from db and push it to S4
- S4 receives data in `onNext()`, doing some work and writes to files

The reason why I need to write data to DB in S3 is because the results that is generated from received data in `onNext()` has to be unique, but as I'm getting data in batches from `Observable1` I can't guaranty this uniqueness, so DB take care of it.

And of course in `S3` I can't just do the same as in `S2` (accumulate all results in memory), because the multiplication of results that exists in S3 is significant comparing to S2.

Comment: This looks waaaay too complicated - what is your use case? Why do you have separated subscribers?

Comment: @TassosBassoukos I edit the question to answer yours

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the clarifications. It seems to me that judicious application of existing Operators will minimize your code. Now, I don't have all the details, but what you're doing feels a lot like this:

```
Observable<T> observable1 = ...
        .share();

Observable<?> S1 = S1(observable1);
Observable<?> S2 = S2(observable1);
Observable<?> S3 = S3(observable1);
Observable<?> S4 = defer(() -> readFromDatabase()).compose(S4::generate);

Observable.merge(S1,S2,S3.ignoreElements().switchIfEmpty(S4))
    .ignoreElements()
    .onComplete(...)
    .subscribe();
```

Of course, the details will be different depending on whether the original observable is hot or cold, and the details of `S[1-4]`.

Also, don't try to drive all `Subscribers` yourself, let the framework do that for you, and you will get so much more out of it - f.e.:

```
S4 = Observable.create(SyncOnSubscribe.generateStateless(
       observer -> observer.onNext(<get List<Foo>>)
   ))
   .takeWhile(list -> someConditionBar);
```

Edit: this is a case of the XY problem - we've all gone through it...